# How to print my app's output on mini2440 screen in console application?

Tags: c++, qt, arm, embedded

I want to print my application out put on mini2440 screen.
I used these command in my Qt console application :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>  


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
  qDebug() << "C++ Style Debug Message";
  qDebug( "C Style Debug Message" );

  system("echo 'system'");
  printf("printf");
  // qFatal does not have a C++ style method.
  qFatal( "C Style Fatal Error Message" );
  return a.exec();
}
```

but all these code just print the statement on my terminal not on mini2440 screen.  after my device boot , i see these line :

> starting networking.....
>   starting web servers....
>   starting LED services....

but I want clean them from screen and show my output on my screen instead
of these lines.
like these:
Hi dear user.

**how can I do that?**
I used mini2440 and wrote application in Qt creator for mini2440 . ( i commented Qtopia to run my program)

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall redirect output of your application to screen, normally it's going to regular output (terminal).

First, verify which tty is representing your screen, on OK6410 bard (similar to yours) it is /dev/tty0. Simple test, type on console:

```
echo test > /dev/tty0
```

and check if text is on screen. If not then try with other tty's available on your board.

Secondary, when screen tty in know, then run application and redirect output:

```
./myTestAppl -qws > /dev/tty0
```

Where tty0 shall be replaced by tty that work for you in first point. Output from application shall show on screen.

[edit]

You can also check which tty is representing screen by review board startup script and check to which tty is send mentioned text "starting networking....." etc.

Comment: yes. Its work. really thanks. it show me the output. but linux logo is not change. how can i clean my desktop?

Comment: I never tested it but shall work: simple filling framebuffer with zeros: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/fb0`

Answer (score 0):

Use a STL: `std::cout`.

`qDebug()` and other predefined Qt I/O streams are not designed to show any output. They are usually used for tracing / logging.

Comment: not worked. when i run my app in terminal host. it just show me the result on my terminal and my mini2440 screen does not change. and not write the output on mini2440 screen

Comment: @hony and what documentation about output says?

Comment: you said right but I want to show it in mini2440 screen after boot. i though if i used echo command it show me the result but i should used ./myTestAppl -qws > /dev/tty0 to show the result on screen.